# How to disable a button on Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

here is my site "Drupal 8" and "Drupal Commerce 2" :

https://www.s1biose.com/produit/savon-artisanal-bio-la-cannelle

I want to disable the "Add to Cart" button. So I added the following code in a JS file of my theme :

```
(function ($) {

  $('.commerce-order-item-add-to-cart-form .btn').prop("disabled", true);

})(window.jQuery);
```

It works, but there is a problem.

When I change the variation of the product, the button activates. Why ?

I want him to be disabled.

On this screenshot it works :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqfv7.png)

In this screenshot, when I change the variation of the product (without reloading the page), the disabled class disappears :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFOcq.png)

Comment: I am guessing this is due to the button (or node) you're setting the prop 'disabled' to true on is being replaced (by a new node) when you change the variation of the product. In order to keep this button disabled you'd have to e.g. set the prop 'disabled' to true each time the variation is changed.

Comment: @Kurzalead thank you for the explanations. How to do this ? https://www.s1biose.com/produit/savon-artisanal-bio-la-cannelle

Comment: I am unable to give you a working example, because I do not have access to your source code. Besides I am uninterested in doing your work for you and rather prompt you to doing some research yourself.

Comment: If the "button" is actually a "link" i.e. an anchor tag, you need to use the `.disabled` class as anchors ignore the disabled property e.g.: `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled"`

Comment: It's difficult to tell by your code as it is not doing any kind of conditional testing to determine the button state. If a user alters the cart content, which usually involves some form of postback, then I assume the button should become active.  So you need to either manage the button state on the server-side or pass button state information to the JQ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the ajax updating it, I would add your code inside a Drupal behavior (behaviors load after ajax):

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.commerceDisableAjax = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.commerce-order-item-add-to-cart-form .btn').prop("disabled", true);    
    }
  };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I created a new JS file in my theme with your code.

Comment: I copy pasted your code. Do I have to customize something? must he left myBehavior

Comment: You can change "myBehavior" to "commerceDisableAjax" or anything that identifies the behavior with that is the function it is accomplishing.

Comment: I do not master JS. I have updated your answer can you tell me if this is correct ?

Comment: Yes, that should do the job :)